# downloading video from youtube objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, download

I'm trying to download video from youtube but getting error.

Error mention in code

my code

```
-(void)downloadVideo{
LBYouTubeExtractor *extractor = [[LBYouTubeExtractor alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:(@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%@"), videoIdToDownload ]] quality:LBYouTubeVideoQualityLarge];
[extractor extractVideoURLWithCompletionBlock:^(NSURL *videoURL, NSError *error) {
    if(!error) {
        NSLog(@"Did extract video URL using completion block: %@", videoURL);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            NSError* error = nil;
            NSData* data1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error]; //data1 is nill
            if (error) { //Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “3gpp;+codecs="mp4v.20.3,+mp4a.40.2"&fallback_host=tc.v8.cache4.googlevideo.com&itag=36” couldn’t be opened."
                NSLog(@"error=%@", error);
            }else{
            NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"video_%@.mp4"), videoIdToDownload ];
            [data1 writeToFile:[dirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] atomically:YES];
            NSLog(@"File %@ successfully saved", filename);
            }
        });
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Failed extracting video URL using block due to error:%@", error);
    }
}];
```

}

using this lib
https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView

If anyone now solution please help me.

Thanks

Comment: what is the purpose you want to download ,

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik  I'm trying to make app like IOS youtube app with download function downloading is requirment

Comment: you may want to open an issue on that github project instead. people knowing that lib might be able to help you faster.

Comment: @GottZ i'm going to open issue on github.
is there is any other way to download video from youtube mean without using that lib?

Comment: i have url with videoID https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YHfz_U-cXxI how can i download this video any idea

Comment: @NisarAhmad sorry i can't help you with that. i'm just one of theese people reviewing questions and answers for quality / if they fit to this community.

Comment: ok thanks for your suggestion of gibhub